# Finding if a point intersects a rotated rectangle?

Tags: c#, xna, intersection

If I have a 2D rectangle of type Microsoft.XNA.Framework.Rectangle and I want to see if a point on screen (defined as (x,y)) goes through it after it has also been rotated by a certain amount?

Comment: A similar question is posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240660/check-if-a-point-is-in-a-rotated-rectangle-c It's in windows forms, but also applies for XNA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rotate about the origin such that the rectangle is aligned along the X & Y axis, then the test becomes simple:

`is rect.left <= point.x <= rect.right, is rect.bottom <= point.y <= rect.top`

If you don't know the rectangle's rotation, you can figure it out with trigonometry.

Comment: Let me know if you want more help with the trig.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but if I rotate the rectangle in the manner you suggest I'll be checking for intersections within a new rectangle which encompasses the rotated rectangle. What I want to do is only check for intersections on the rectangle that was rotated

Comment: If you rotate both the rectangle and the point, the "new rectangle" is really the same rectangle, just aligned nicely so you can easily check its bounds. To see how this works, draw (on paper) a rectangle on a 45 degree angle, along with some point. Now tilt your head 45 degrees and the rectangle will look like it's no longer rotated.

Answer (score 2):

Can you un-rotate both the rectangle and the point and then see if point is inside with simple bounds checking?

By unrotate I mean that one of the edges of the rectangle is aligned with the x-axis.