# How to draw a rotated rectangle

Tags: java, android, graphics

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQGTE.png]

Can anyone share a code how to draw a rectangle like this?
(not vertical, not horizontal, somewhere between)
Because as I see you can only specify 4 `int`s to function `DrawRect()`, not 4 points.

**The area of rectangle must be sensitive to touch (I use Contains() method)**

*As I tried, Matrix and Rotate() update only graphics, the rect's area remains the same it was*

Comment: You might want to clarify that you want someone to be able to put their finger in there and have the program sense the touch within the rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution - the easiest way is to use Path class, make a free-turned rectangle by points and then create a region method, which has function Contains()

No need for math and hard work, pretty and easy.

Answer (score 1):

After transforming as @fortran suggested, you can use one of the [Matrix.mapPoints](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#mapPoints%28float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D%29) overloads to find out what the new corners of your rectangle are. You'll probably have to find some fancy math and do hit testing yourself. Might be easier to call Matrix.mapPoints() on the [inverse](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#invert%28android.graphics.Matrix%29) of the transformation used to draw the rectangle, passing the touched coordinates, and then hit test on the original rectangle.

Comment: might be but.Im not good in math. can you probably show the solution...?

Comment: I haven't ever written up any code (and don't have access to the Java SDK right now) but [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240660/check-if-a-point-is-in-a-rotated-rectangle-c) concludes the same idea and @JeffH's answer links to the math if inverting isn't practical for you.

Answer (score 0):

Push a rotation transformation, draw the rectangle, pop it.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#rotate%28float,%20float,%20float%29

Comment: As I tried, Matrix transforms only graphics, physical area of rectangle remains the same, and I didnt find a Contrains() method (exept Rect.Contains()) to check if point is inside of new Rectangle.

Comment: rotation also doesn't update the rectangle's area, it updated the graphics (and left a "fantom" rectangle area), but then how can I determine if some point is inside of rotated rect?